# How can I use template in my own component vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using **BTable** from **bootstrap-vue** in my own component, so that I can reuse this component. What I want to do is use the BTable templates in my Component.

```
<MyTable>
    <template #cell(entrada)="data">
            ...
    </template>        
</MyTable>
```

And then, being able to use #cell in the MyTable component, to include it in BTable.
This would be the MyTable component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-table striped hover :items="filteredItems" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" class="dataTable">
            <template #cell(entrada)="data">
            ...
            </template>
        </b-table>
        <div class="mt-5">  
            <b-pagination
                v-model="currentPage"
                :total-rows="filteredCount"
                :per-page="perPage"
                aria-controls="my-table"
            ></b-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js pass slot to wrapped Bootstrap-Vue Table component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435381/vue-js-pass-slot-to-wrapped-bootstrap-vue-table-component)

Comment: yes @Hiws, is exactly this